# Loop a sprite background-position in increments on scrollLeft

Tags: javascript, html, css, sprite

I have one full page `DIV` that scrolls horizontally, called `#SCROLL`.

I have one 210x310 `DIV` with an 8 frame sprite, called `#TRICYCLE`.

What I'm trying to do is when `#SCROLL` moves left or right, that the `background-position` of `#TRICYCLE` loops forwards or backwards in 210px increments.

Any help on a solution or advice on where else to look (believe me, I have looked) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us a little code and what have you tried ?

Comment: Is it You, who causes #scroll to move? If yes, update tricycle backgroundPosition whenever You move the #scroll. Where's the problem?

Comment: The main problem is I'm still learning javascript, so writing 'update tricycle' doesn't help someone like me. Sorry.

I seem to be having troubles working out the comment formatting here too. Sorry again.

`
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  $("#tricycle").css('background-position', ( ( $(window).scrollLeft() / 105 ) * -210 ) + 'px center');
  });
});
`

Comment: The code I 'attempted' to post here, works with using the mousewheel, as that moves the content 105px, but when I use the scrollbar, it moves the sprite 1px at a time, not the 210px I'm after.

If anyone has some suggestions, please take into account I may need a bit more explanation than your average Joe. Still learnin'.

Thanks

Comment: I should've started with something you could look at. I've just put what I've been working on online:  
<http://nickverburgt.com/test/nickverburgtdesigns >